# Python sql returning list

Tags: python, sql

got some functions with sqlstatements. My first func is fine because i get only 1 result.
My second function returns a large list of errorcodes and i dont know how to get them back for response.

```
TypeError: &lt;sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x7f98b85ef910&gt; is not JSON serializable
```

Tried everything need help.
My Code:

```
def topalarms():
    customer_name = request.args.get('customer_name')
    machine_serial = request.args.get('machine_serial')

    #ts = request.args.get('ts')
    #ts_start = request.args.get('ts')

    if (customer_name is None) or (machine_serial is None):
        return missing_param()
    # def form_response(response, session):
        # response['customer'] = customer_name
        # response['serial'] = machine_serial

    # return do_response(customer_name, form_response)
    def form_response(response, session):
        result_machine_id = machine_id(session, machine_serial)
        if not result_machine_id:
            response['Error'] = 'Seriennummer nicht vorhanden/gefunden'
            return   
        #response[''] = result_machine_id[0]["id"]
        machineid = result_machine_id[0]["id"]
        result_errorcodes = error_codes(session, machineid)        
        response['ErrorCodes'] = result_errorcodes
        
    return do_response(customer_name, form_response)

def machine_id(session, machine_serial):

    stmt_raw = '''
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            machine
        WHERE 
            machine.serial = :machine_serial_arg
        '''    
    utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    utc_now_iso = pytz.utc.localize(utc_now).isoformat()
        
    utc_start = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days = 30)
    utc_start_iso = pytz.utc.localize(utc_start).isoformat()
        
    stmt_args = {
        'machine_serial_arg': machine_serial,
        }
        
    stmt = text(stmt_raw).columns(
        #ts_insert = ISODateTime
        )
        
    result = session.execute(stmt, stmt_args)
        
    ts = utc_now_iso
    ts_start = utc_start_iso
    
    ID = []

    for row in result:
        ID.append({
            'id': row[0],
            'ts': ts,
            'ts_start': ts_start,
            })
    return ID

def error_codes(session, machineid):

    stmt_raw = '''
        SELECT
            name
        FROM
            identifier
        WHERE
            identifier.machine_id = :machineid_arg         
        '''    
        
    stmt_args = {
        'machineid_arg': machineid,
        }
        
    stmt = text(stmt_raw).columns(
        #ts_insert = ISODateTime
        )
        
    result = session.execute(stmt, stmt_args)
    
    errors = []
    
    for row in result:
        errors.append(result)
    #({'result': [dict(row) for row in result]})
    #errors = {i: result[i] for i in range(0, len(result))}
    #errors = dict(result)
    return errors
```

My problem is func error_codes somethiing is wrong with my result.
my Output should be like this:

```
ABCNormal
ABCSafety
Alarm_G01N01
Alarm_G01N02
Alarm_G01N03
Alarm_G01N04
Alarm_G01N05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a closer look at what you are doing correctly with your working function and compare that to your non-working function.

Firstly, what do you think this code does?

```py
   for row in result:
        errors.append(result)
```

This adds to `errors` one copy of the `result` object for each row in `result`.  So if you have six rows in `result`, `errors` contains six copies of `result`.  I suspect this isn't what you are looking for.  You want to be doing something with the `row` variable.

Taking a closer look at your working function, you are taking the first value out of the row, using `row[0]`.  So, you probably want to do the same in your non-working function:

```py
   for row in result:
        errors.append(row[0])
```

I don't have SQLAlchemy set up so I haven't tested this: I have provided this answer based solely on the differences between your working function and your non-working function.

Answer (score 0):

You need a json serializer. I suggest using Marshmallow: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

There are some great tutorials online on how to do this.

Comment: there must be another possibility like in the func machine_id

Comment: What is you aversion to using Marshmallow? It was literally design for this exact purpose, and works beautifully with SQLAlchemy.